# How to use regex to split a string into several parts

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string `'    DIM D =9999  \ PE TS                         D(A(4))'`
and want to use regex expression to divided this string into several parts. Note that `'DIM'` `'='` is constant and after `=` is always a number but after the number, the content may change a lot. But the space between `'DIM'` and `'='` may be different string by string. This variance is also applied to the following substring. Also, I want to have  `'PE TS'` to be recognized as one element.
So, I am thinking this string can have several groups: `'DIM'`,`'D'`, `'=9999'`, `'\'`, `'PE TS'`, `'D(A(4))'`.

I've tried re.match but I cannot find a good pattern expression for it.

```
match = re.match('(DIM\s+\S)(\d*)(\S+)([\w\s]*)(\s*\w*)', line)
```

I expected to see:

```
'DIM', '= 9999', '\', 'PE TS','D(A(4))'
```

But, I always get None returned.

Comment: try to use this: https://regex101.com/

Comment: you need to use `split`, not `match`

Comment: Also "re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the string." ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match))

Comment: I feel split may not work. Because the space between each element may be different. Even though my code works for this string. But, I worry it may not work for other similar string. Am I right?

Comment: Are you trying to parse VB? if so, there might be a better way to do this using a parser if you plan to do this en masse.

Comment: @Eric you should give another example and expected result for better help.

Comment: @בנימיןכהן Thank you so much. I tried this tool and I solved my problem.

Comment: @AaronBell I agree. I used re.compile and research. I solved my problem.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 No, I am trying to read from a text file and pass some string to my variables. Thanks

Comment: @Eric I don't see what that has to do with what I said. Also, you should not include the answer in your question. Your question should stay the same as it was before you found an answer. Answers are written below.

Comment: @Eric I rolled back your question. Solutions should be posted as answers. You can post an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, an expression somewhat similar to,

```
(DIM\s+\S+)\s*(=\s*\d+)\s*(\S+)\s*(.+?)\s{2,}(.+)
```

might just work OK, not sure though.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(DIM\s+\S+)\s*(=\s*\d+)\s*(\S+)\s*(.+?)\s{2,}(.+)"
test_str = """
   DIM D =9999  \ PE TS                         D(A(4))
    DIM AZ =    9999  \   PE TS AC AB                         D(A(4))
"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
[('DIM D', '=9999', '\\', 'PE TS', 'D(A(4))'), ('DIM AZ', '=    9999', '\\', 'PE TS AC AB', 'D(A(4))')]
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pPAOom/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/pPAOom/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: I think you are missing the `=`?

Comment: I used a slightly different pattern with you. So, I haven't tried yours. But, it seems to work. And I agree regext101 is fabulous.

Comment: @Emma I've been thinking about your solution, and I think I understand how `re.findall` works. It uses `(RegEx)`, finds a match, then delimits (ignores) the string based on non-`()` regex until it then finds a string matching the next `(RegEx)` group. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I read that, and I definitely wouldn't've understood that without your example.

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure `match` won't do what you're expecting because:

1. Assuming your regex selected all the items on your list (there was nothing to handle the `\`, `(` and `)`), `match` only selects things at the beginning of the string.
2. Assuming you used `search` and had the right regex, `search` would match `DIM D =9999  \ PE TS                         D(A(4))` and not split it.
3. Assuming you did use search, had the right regex, and it had a match, you'd need to use `.group()` or `.groups()` after `re.search(...)` to retrieve the matches as strings.
4. Assuming you did have a function that split the string like you wanted to, it'd be in separate regex blocks (one for `DIM`, one for `=9999`, etc.)

Here's how I split the string, though Emma's answer may be better:

```py
import re

myString = '    DIM D =9999  \ PE TS                         D(A(4))'

# DIM D
dim = re.search('(DIM\s+\S)', myString).group()
equals9999 = re.search('(=\s*\d+)', myString).group()
backslash = re.search(r'\\', myString).group()
twoDoubleLetters = re.search(r'\\(\s+\w+\s+\w+)', myString).group()[2:]
cellMarker = re.search(r'\w\(\w\(\d\)\)', myString).group()

print(dim) # DIM D
print(equals9999) # =9999
print(backslash) # \
print(twoDoubleLetters) # PE TS
print(cellMarker) # D(A(4))
```